# iphone video upload in queue

Tags: iphone, ios, video, upload

I need to record video and upload them to Server. They will be added in queue and uploaded one by one.

My question is, when i record a video, where should i save it till it gets uploaded ?
Should i save it in Album ? or in private documents directory ?

I also need to delete the video once it is uploaded.

According to ios guidelines, is it required to save the video in Albums only ? Will my app be rejected if it is saved in Documents directory for longer period?

Answer (score 1):

If they are not user-created (or if you do not want them to participate in stuff like iCloud), then do not put them in APPHOME/Documents.

The preferred location is APPHOME/Library/Caches but that location can get cleaned by the iOS on a system restore (and possibly other times -- documentation does not specify).  It's not going to happen on a regular basis though, so it's the first option if you can regenerate the data on rare occasions like restore.

So, if the files can be recreated, keep them in APPHOME/Library/Caches.  If they cannot, then place them somewhere else in APPHOME/Library.

Just make sure you remove them when you are done with the upload.

Answer (score 0):

You're ok, you can save/delete them in/from the `Documents` directory. Instead, you can't delete videos/photos from the user's albums. No problem for the "longer period".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
But based on the final ios data storage guidelines which make things mark for cloud backup or not, will it effect in my sitution ? i may end up in storing around 20-30 videos at some point of time which will be in queue .

The iOS Data Storage Guidelines indicate that only content that the user creates using your app, e.g., documents, new files, edits, etc., may be stored in the /Documents directory - and backed up by iCloud.

How do i manage them then? i will be needing them till they are uploaded ?

Comment: @ChigigulaDewan Ok, there is a flag "do not back up", you can set this to the folder you don't want to backup, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092256/backing-up-prevent-from-the-app-in-icloud)

Comment: Thanks again for the quick reply.   One more question along with this,  so now that i have to mark it as 'do not back up' , i need to have xcode 4.3.2 ( for ios 5) . Now i only have xcode 4.2 which can build upto 4.2 only.

Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Yes, iColud is present from iOS 5 so you have to upgrade your enviornment to build iOS 5 apps.