# Prevent app from backing up documents folder?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, backup, icloud

I'm trying to prevent my app backing up files to iCloud but have become completely confused and a little lost.

-EDIT-

I've updated this to reflect the changes I've made thanks to the posters below.

I want to prevent back up of files which are downloaded to the app's documents directory.

So far I have a class called `PreventBackup` with the following method:

```
+ (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL
{    
   NSError *error = nil;
   BOOL success = [URL setResourceValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]
                              forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: &error];
   if(!success){
       NSLog(@"Error excluding %@ from backup %@", [URL lastPathComponent], error);
   }
   NSLog(@"prevent backup method called without error");
   return success;
}
```

I'm then calling it with this code when the app starts:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSURL *pathURL= [NSURL fileURLWithPath:documentsDirectory];
[PreventBackup addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:pathURL];
```

The cosole prints `prevent backup method called without error` but the app is still showing as having the same amount of data for back up with it did before.

Any idea where this is going wrong?

-EDIT 2-

OK, I think this is solved. The files are downloading to a sub folder called "downloads". changing the code above so that it reads as follows appears to have done the trick:

```
NSString *downloadsFolder = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:(@"/downloads")];
NSURL *pathURL= [NSURL fileURLWithPath:downloadsFolder];
[PreventBackup addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:pathURL];
```

Thanks to all for your help.

Comment: check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866590/prevent-icloud-backup-of-folder?lq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092256/backing-up-prevent-from-the-app-in-icloud?rq=1

Comment: Thanks. I'd already seen the second link and it didn't help but the first one does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL
{

    assert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: [URL path]]);

    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL success = [URL setResourceValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]
                                  forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: &error];
    if(!success){
        NSLog(@"Error excluding %@ from backup %@", [URL lastPathComponent], error);
    }
    return success;
}

NSURL *documentURLWithExtension = [documentURL URLByAppendingPathExtension:extensionType];
```

pass this "`documentURLWithExtension`" to this function

```
[self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:documentURLWithExtension];
```

Comment: Thanks very much. This seems to do the trick with one little caveat; I need to comment out `assert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: [URL path]]);`

Answer (score 6):

**In Swift:**

```
//Path of document directory
var docPathAry : NSArray! = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
var docDirPathStr: AnyObject? = docPathAry.count > 0 ? docPathAry[0] : nil

self.addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL(NSURL.fileURLWithPath(docDirPathStr as NSString))
```

and:

```
func addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL(URL: NSURL!) -> Bool {
    assert(NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(URL.path))
    var err : NSError? = nil
    var success : Bool! = URL.setResourceValue(NSNumber.numberWithBool(true), forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey, error: &err)

    if(!success) {
        println("Error excluding \(URL.lastPathComponent) from backup\(err) ")
    }

    return success
}
```