# Phonegap 3.5.0 app - prevent iCloud backup

Tags: ios, cordova, storage

I've just got a rejection from Apple for a web-app I built with Phonegap due to not following Data Storage Guidelines.

In config.xml I've set the "BackupWebStorage" preference to "local" but this doesn't work anymore.

This app doesn't write files on the devices, but it only use some ajax calls and the related JSON object.

What kind of setting I have to use to prevent the backup of any data the app will generate?

Comment: This any help?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682859/prevent-app-from-backing-up-documents-folder

Comment: Could this help you? http://jorgenmodin.net/index_html/prevent-icloud-backup-of-phonegaps-localstorage

Comment: @rob: i'm using Phonegap not ios;

Comment: @genie: what u suggest is my issue

Comment: Understood. Does it not work when you even set "none" for BackupWebStorage?

Comment: Yes. It seems that the property is no longer working.

Comment: Same issue for me. I'm trying to find a solution since yesterday